# Taxonomy Query Relation field not behaving correctly?

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

This is my post entries with categories and tags

[image]

I am using Taxonomy query

**When I use relation AND** - Tax Query for Category **Geed** + Tag **Cool**

Nothing shows up.

But **When I use relation OR**
2 The post shows up.

isn't supposed to work the opposite way?

Comment: Where is a problem? On your screen no posts with `Greed` category and `Cool` tag, that's why you see nothing - AND means that post has both terms.

Comment: @anton Got the logic, Thanks I was thinking that it will list the post with Geed category and cool tag separately ..didn't know that the post needs to have both terms